# i have a list view that contain two views textview and edittext. how i can get entire edittext data after pressing a single button

Tags: android

i have one textview and one edittext in a single row inside a list view ..
now i want to get values entered inside the edittext one by one and store it in an array (array of objects. each object  contain two variables that will hold these two views data of single rows)
 . i have a button at the bottom of this layout that contain the listview . my question is how i can do it when i press that button and  after pressing  my entire edittext values will get one by one and will store in the array.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: That is not possible. As views get recycled. If you have 400 items in your adapter and the listview displays say 10 then you can type something in 10 EditText's. But as soon as the user srolls the list and then comes back to the same 10 items you will see that the EditText's lost their content. Didn't you see that already? If you want to get the content from the edits you have to grab them before they scroll from the screen.